# ContentHandler make callbacks in wrong order

Tags: android, html, css, saxparser

I'm Using ContentHandler to parse custom html with css styles. 
The problem is - ContentHandler missbehaves when I'm trying  to parse HTML with `UL` tag.
It calls `startTag()` then `endTag()` then `characters()`

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>ul.ul1{list-style-type:image;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="ul1">List</ul>
<ul class="ul2">List</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Sample code to test parser

```
public class ContentHandler implements org.xml.sax.ContentHandler {
    public ContentHandler() {
    }

    public Spanned getResult() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        Log.d("html_parser", "start " + localName);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        Log.d("html_parser", "end " + localName);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        String bodyText = new String(ch, start, length);
        Log.d("html_parser", bodyText);
    }

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
    }
}
```

And LogCat output

```
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start html
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start head
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start meta
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end meta
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start style
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ ul.ul1{list-style-type:image;}
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end style
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end head
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start body
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start ul
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end ul
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ List
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ start ul
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end ul
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ List
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end body
02-13 13:18:41.555  13211-13211/com.example D/html_parser﹕ end html
```

Please notice, when I'm parsing HTML without `UL` tag it works OK. Also notice that for parsing org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXParserImpl are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested your problem and found some intrested fact. You have use SAX parser for parsing html, so html has a lot differences from xml. for example sometimes tags can be unclosed, etc. So org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXParserImpl allow us to parse html. Also that parser wraps some addition tags https://github.com/websdotcom/tagsoup#what-tagsoup-does. Look for html in the next code. if you will add correct structure of content it processed normally. So I think that this is like bug in TagSoup lib.

```
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXParserImpl;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;

/**
 * Created by kulik on 1/5/14.
 */
public class SaxTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    private static final String TAG = "SaxTest";

    public void testSax() {
        String testString = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
               "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n" +
                "<style>ul.ul1{list-style-type:image;}\n" +
                "</style>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<ul class=\"ul1\">List</ul>\n" +
                "<ul class=\"ul2\">" +
                "<li> li1</li>\n" +
                "<li> li2</li>\n" +
                "</ul>" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";

        Reader reader = new StringReader(testString);
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserImpl.newInstance(null);
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            DefaultHandler myHandler = new ContentHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(reader));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
    }

    public class ContentHandler extends DefaultHandler  {

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            Log.d("html_parser", "start " + localName);
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            Log.d("html_parser", "end " + localName);
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            String bodyText = new String(ch, start, length);
            Log.d("html_parser", bodyText);
        }
    }
}
```

and log

```
  D/html_parser﹕ start html
  D/html_parser﹕ start head
  D/html_parser﹕ start meta
  D/html_parser﹕ end meta
  D/html_parser﹕ start style
  D/html_parser﹕ ul.ul1{list-style-type:image;}
  D/html_parser﹕ end style
  D/html_parser﹕ end head
  D/html_parser﹕ start body
  D/html_parser﹕ start ul
  D/html_parser﹕ end ul
  D/html_parser﹕ List
  D/html_parser﹕ start ul
  D/html_parser﹕ start li
  D/html_parser﹕ li1
  D/html_parser﹕ end li
  D/html_parser﹕ start li
  D/html_parser﹕ li2
  D/html_parser﹕ end li
  D/html_parser﹕ end ul
  D/html_parser﹕ end body
  D/html_parser﹕ end html
```

So you can implement your handler to catch that situation, because i think this is connected only with  tags without any

. Maybe it appears because:

> The semantics of TagSoup are as far as practical those of actual HTML
>   browsers. In particular, never, never will it throw any sort of syntax
>   error: the TagSoup motto is "Just Keep On Truckin'". But there's much,
>   much more. For example, if the first tag is LI, it will supply the
>   application with enclosing HTML, BODY, and UL tags. Why UL? Because
>   that's what browsers assume in this situation. For the same reason,
>   overlapping tags are correctly restarted wheneve.......

http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

also you can ask tagsoup team.